# D3+Leaflet map.on() issue - running function during (or after) drag event

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, leaflet, drag

I'm working with D3+leaflet and have a question - my SVG elements seem to disappear outside the scope of the map frame when I zoom in. Meaning, that when I zoom in the map, and then drag to a different frame, the SVG elements aren't loaded. So i'd like to execute a map.on( ) function for drag events but I'm having trouble.

So for when you zoom in, replotting the SVGs work fine with the `map.on("viewreset")` - but `map.on("drag")` or `map.on("dragend")` seems to have no effect.

```
  var cheat_function = function() { reset(data); drawHour( orderedColumns[currentFrame] )};

    map.on("viewreset", cheat_function);

    map.on("dragend", cheat_function)
```

The contents inside cheat_function just do stuff like recalculating the coordinates and redrawing the SVGs.

Any ideas or hacks? thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the `moveend` event:

> Fired when the view of the map stops changing (e.g. user stopped
>   dragging the map).